# Different pagination conditions with query strings [CakePHP 3]

Tags: php, url, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

The user has to pass in the URL a query string which will return different pagination, if he entered none, one or both queries, the result will change. The code below works in CakePHP, but it looks horrible, is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do without those if, else if conditions?

```
if($this->request->query('date')) 
{ 
    $this->paginate = [ 
        'conditions' => [ 
          'Reservations.id_venue' => $this->Auth->user('id_venue_manager'), 
          'Reservations.date' => $this->request->query('date'), 
        ], 
    ]; 
} 
else if($this->request->query('id_user')) 
{ 
    $this->paginate = [ 
       'conditions' => [ 
          'Reservations.id_venue' => $this->Auth->user('id_venue_manager'), 
          'Reservations.id_user' => $this->request->query('id_user'), 
        ], 
    ]; 
} 
else if($this->request->query('id_user') && $this->request->query('date')) 
{ 
    $this->paginate = [ 
       'conditions' => [ 
          'Reservations.id_venue' => $this->Auth->user('id_venue_manager'), 
          'Reservations.id_user' => $this->request->query('id_user'), 
          'Reservations.date' => $this->request->query('date'), 
       ], 
    ]; 
} 
else 
{ 
    $this->paginate = [ 
       'conditions' => [ 
          'Reservations.id_venue' => $this->Auth->user('id_venue_manager'), 
       ], 
   ]; 
}
```

Comment: I would use this plugin instead https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

public function someMethod() {
     $this->paginate = [ 
       'conditions' => $this->getPaginationConditions();
    ]; 
}

private function getPaginationConditions()
{
    $conditions = ['Reservations.id_venue' => $this->Auth->user('id_venue_manager')];  

    if ($date = $this->request->query('date')) {
        $conditions['Reservations.date'] = $date;
    }

    if ($user = $this->request->query('id_user')) {
        $conditions['Reservations.id_user'] = $user;
    }

    return $conditions;
}
```